# SQL*Plus > Is current date available in a system variable or some sort?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm regularly spooling results or messages of processing programs to a file. To prevent spool files getting overwritten, I use date and time in spool filenames.
Using the construction COLUMN {var1} NEW_VALUE {var2} and a SELECT-statement is a lot of code for just having the current date. When spooling I want to suppress output of this construction, since it is not needed in a spool file. That takes extra coding.

Is the current date and time available in SQL*Plus?

I'm using this code:

```
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF
SET termout OFF

COLUMN bestandsnaam NEW_VALUE _vv_waarde

SELECT to_char ( sysdate, 'yyyyddmm_hh24mi') bestandsnaam
FROM DUAL;

SPOOL Verwerking_&_vv_waarde.

{ processing }

SPOOL OFF
```

But I'd like to have sysdate or something like that available in SQL*Plus
so I could code something like:

```
SPOOL Verwerking_#sysdate#

{ processing }

SPOOL OFF
```

Spool file will be named 'Verwerking_20190409_1904'.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a predefined `_DATE` variable ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#SQPUG038)). But since all SQL*Plus variables are character datatype, you have to set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to the string you want.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyyddmm_hh24mi';
SPOOL Verwerking_&_DATE.
...
SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of using current date and time in spool file name except what you are doing. (As far as I know)

But Yes, You can use following code if it suits your requirement:

```
dateVar=`date +%d-%b-%Y_%H%M%S`

sqlplus .......
spool Verwerking_'${dateVar}'
select ...; -- your query
spool off
Exit
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do it.

If you have a number of scripts and simply want to avoid having to put this code in you can have this code in a script that you call, e.g.

get_date.sql:

```
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF
SET termout OFF

COLUMN bestandsnaam NEW_VALUE _vv_waarde

SELECT to_char ( sysdate, 'yyyyddmm_hh24mi') bestandsnaam
FROM DUAL;

SET echo ON
SET feedback ON
SET termout ON
```

Then in each script you can simply:

```
@get_date.sql
SPOOL Verwerking_&_vv_waarde.
PROMPT The date is &_vv_waarde

{ processing }

SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: Judging by @kfinity answer below I stand corrected in there being a predefined parameter. I guess a quick `define` in SQLPLUS would have shown this.